# How to "stealthily" call a Java function to avoid text search?

Tags: android, java

Assume I am an attacker, I want to call an API function from an Android app, say `Build.getRadioVersion()`. But I want to keep this call stealthy, i.e., it cannot be searched through, e.g., `grep getRadioVersion`.

One way is to use reflection, but it is still obvious and thus can be located quickly, since reflection is rarely used in "normal" code.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thought: Security through obscurity is pathetic.

Comment: I would rather call it obfuscations.

Comment: Which is the only security obfuscation can ever really offer.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but wont something like [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) help? Or perhaps it will not obfuscate API calls?

Comment: The only ways of calling the method are either calling it directly or calling it using reflection. If you are worried about any particular bit of code standing out as being obfuscated then use an automated obfuscation tool on the whole thing.